# Reading a 2D char array from file in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, char, 2d, fstream

First off my knowledge of c++ is very limited this is my first class so this may look dumb but bear with me, i would ask that you please keep it somewhat simple or explain very well thanks in advance.

Ok the goal is i want to create this file with the rules inside so that i can read it in in a separate function. However when i run this i get no errors but it comes out firstly with no spaces at all and i get some random ascii at the end.

here is the results of running the code
Welcometothetypinggame1.Typetheentiresentenceinoneline2.IstimedandwillaffectthescoreØ-™wîú{   Dx&a¼ Ë' ©ÉaDx&a®pa

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
//set the sentences i want the file to print
char o[3][40]={"Welcome to the typing game             ",
            "1. Type the entire sentence in one line",
            "2. Is timed and will affect the score  "};

//creating the file to read in
ofstream out;
out.open("rules.txt");
for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
    for(int x=0; x<39; x++){
        out<<o[i][x];
    }
    out<<"\n";
}
out.close();


//creating a new array to read the data that was stored above
char a[3][40];
ifstream in;
in.open("rules.txt");
for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
    for(int x=0; x<40; x++){
        in>>a[i][x];
    }
}
in.close();

//and just printing out the array to see the results
for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
    for(int x=0; x<40; x++){
        cout<<a[i][x];
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem lies here:

```
in>>a[i][x];
```

The extraction operator `>>` extracts formatted data. Formatted data means that blocks of characters separated by whitespace (like space). During extraction, all whitespace characters are ignored. So you can't read whitespace character using `>>` operator.

What you need to do is to read as unformated data:

```
in.get(a[i][x]);
```

Read more [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/operator%3E%3E/) and [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/get/).

Comment: Thanks for the quick well explained answer

Answer (score 2):

Do not use >> in this particular example. It reads formatted data from your file. Either use

```
in.get(a[i][x]);
```

Or even better, drop your char arrays and declare them as strings and put them in a dynamic container, let's say vector.

```
ifstream in("rules.txt");
vector<string> myLines;
while (!in.eof()) {
    string temp;
    getline(in,temp);
    myLines.push_back(temp);
}
```

Now you have all your rules in separate strings stored in a vector. It is also easy to write them to a file. When you are iterating with your for loop from 0 to 40, and the string is not 40 characters long, you get your "random ascii".

Answer (score 1):

The extraction operator >> will ignore white spaces by default.
You can either read unformated data as suggested in the other answers
or you can change the default behavior like this :

```
in.open("rules.txt");
in >> noskipws;
for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
    for(int x=0; x<40; x++){
        in>>a[i][x];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Part 1**

> it comes out firstly with no spaces

the problem is here

```
for(int x=0; x<39; x++){
   out<<o[i][x];
}
```

You write only the data, and you do not format your output.

You have two possible solutions:

1. use `<iomanip>` and use `setw` and `setfill`
2. add a whitespace after (or before) every entry.

Example for the second option:

```
for(int x=0; x<39; x++) {
    out << o[i][x] <<" ";
}
```

Obviously this will put spaces also after the last entry (or before the first). Additional code is required if you do not want this.

**Part 2**

> i get some random ascii at the end

The problem (as stated by others) lies here:

```
for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
    for(int x=0; x<39; x++)
```

You arbitrarily limit/increase your output disregarding the actual size of the variable you have to write/read.

For writing (it is the same for screen or file) you should do something like (please note that this is a solution if `o` is a vector of vectors, not a char array. I prefer not to use arrays.)

```
for(int i=0;i<o.size();i++){
    for(int x=0; x<o[0].size(); x++)
```

For reading, instead, you need to check if you are changing line and/or if you reached the end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

If i remember correctly, the lack of /n at the end of each line would prevent the 'wordwrap' and it would all appear on one line.